# How do I list multiple items in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

What is the proper syntax for the below code:

```
SELECT * FROM this WHERE x = 'y' AND id != '10, 11, 143'
```

The part I am not sure about is listing multiple IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `id` is numeric, you can use

```
SELECT * FROM this WHERE x = 'y' AND id not in (10,11,143)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM this WHERE x = 'y' AND id not in ('10','11','143')
```

for strings.